# Can't delete Windows folder that contains a subfolder named "..." which contains a subfolder named "..." etc

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments, subdirectory, delete-file

I'm stumped.
I have a folder called `c:/data/ToDelete`.  It used to contain files as well as a single subfolder called `...`, which contained the same files as well as single subfolder named `...` and this went on ad nauseum.

I moved the contents of the ToDelete folder elsewhere, but the subfolder/subfolder structure remains, and I can't get rid of it.

This is what it looks like in Explorer
`This PC > Data > ToDelete > ... > ... > ... > ... > etc`
clicking on the above reveals the path: `C:\Data\ToDelete\`

I was able to rename the first folder (from c:/data/temp/ to c:/data/ToDelete/) but whenever I try to rename the subfolder I get the "This folder is already open" (probably because it is just referring back to it's parent folder).

Things I've tried (none worked)

- the basics: Delete key, Shift Delete, drag to recycle bin, send to recycle bin
- command prompt delete, including trying the ASCII code for `.` just in case.
- I tried zipping it with 7zip
- I did a chkdsk and got no errors
- I tried removing with Revo Uninstaller Pro (the Delete folder option).
- I tried renaming the subfolders with this powershell script that I found online thinking I could then delete them but got an error:

```
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse | where {$_.attributes -eq "Directory"} | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '...'} | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '...' , 'ToDelete' }
```

The funny thing is I found the folder in my backup directory as well, so somehow the entire thing can get copied (which means I have to remove it in multiple places now).

Comment: Make an empty folder and try the `robocopy c:\empty c:\data\ToDelete /MIR` trick to mirror an empty directory over the top of that one. Be a bit careful and have backups, Robocopy MIR will delete data so if the command isn't right, it could delete the wrong data.

Comment: TessellatingHeckler I didn't notice your comment and tried zett42's method so I can't be sure if your method would have worked, but I nonetheless wanted to thank you for answering, and I have copied your solution to my personal 'help file'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things to enable PowerShell to process files or folders literally named `...`:

- Use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path` parameter where possible, to prevent PowerShell from parsing the path.
- Prepend `\\?\` to the *full* path to tell the underlying [Windows APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-file-namespaces) to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows it straight to the file system.

**Example:**

```sh
# For demonstration, create two nested sub folders literally named '...'
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path '\\?\c:\data\ToDelete\...\...'

# Rename all '...' sub folders to 'ToDelete'
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '\\?\c:\data\ToDelete' -Directory -Recurse -Filter '...' | 
    Sort-Object { $_.Fullname.Length } -Desc | 
    Rename-Item -NewName ToDelete
```

- Before renaming the folders, we must sort by path length (descending) to make sure that deepest nested folders will be renamed first. Otherwise paths enumerated by `Get-ChildItem` would be incorrect after renaming the first folder.

For what you have tried:

- Note that `-match '...'` doesn't find folders named literally like "...". The `-match` operator's RHS operand is a *regular expression pattern* and as such would match the first sequence of *any* three characters in the string. The same can be said about `-replace '...'`. To *literally* match "...", use `-eq '...'` or escape the dots like this when used in RegEx pattern: `\.\.\.`